# Linear Process Definition error?

Tags: time-series, linear-model, autoregressive

In Introduction to Time Series Forceasting by Brockwell and Davis (3rd ed.), Chapter 2 contains the following definition of a linear process:

> Time series $\{X_t\}$ is a linear process if it has representation
> $$
> >X_t = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \psi_j Z_{t-j} \ \ \forall t
> >$$
> where $\{Z_t\} \sim \text{WN}(0, \sigma^2$ and $\{\psi_j \}$ is a sequence of constants >with $\sum_{j=−\infty}^\infty \ |\psi_j| < \infty$

However, several other sources ([here is an example](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/time-series-analysis/9780470272848/11_chap03.html#:%7E:text=CHAPTER%20THREE-,Linear%20Stationary%20Models,linear%20aggregation%20of%20random%20shocks.&text=Parsimony%20may%20often%20be%20achieved,autoregressive%20and%20moving%20average%20terms.)) define a linear process in this way:

$$
X_t = Z_0 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \psi_j Z_{t-j}
$$

The latter makes sense to me while the former leaves me confused. By Brockwell's definition the index $j$ can take the value $-10$ while the time index $t$ may take the value $1$. In this example, $X_1$ would then be dependent on $Z_{1-(-10)} = Z_{11}$ which is in the future relative to $X_1$. How can $X_1$ be dependent on something that has not occurred yet temporally? Is this an error in Brockwell & Davis? I am unable to find an errata for this book.

Comment: If you go on to read the book, you will find material on "existence of a causal representation", which corresponds to the second definition, hopefully clarifying they indeed mean what they write. So their more general definition also covers what is known noncausal cases. But you are right that the definitions are not always used in exactly the same way in the literature.

Comment: Ok thank you for this tip. I will check out that section.